# Cannot resolve onPause method for React Native sample app

Tags: react-native

I try to implement https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

but when I try to implement the activity lifecycle callbacks onPause, onResume and onDestroy, my Android Studio complains: cannot resolve method onPause.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10326

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that using onHostPause instead of onPause shall be solution,same solves other callbacks complains.

Checking this [commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/19a1c4c22985ea6c7b475db71681bfc4dac4f1e0) for detail:

Answer (score 0):

I used it following way:

```
@Override
public void onHostResume() {
    Log.i(TAG, "- onResume");
     // Within {@code onPause()}, we pause location updates, but leave the
     // connection to GoogleApiClient intact.  Here, we resume receiving
    // location updates if the user has requested them.
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        checkLocationSettings();
        Log.i(TAG,"on resume");
    }
}

@Override
public void onHostPause() {
    Log.i(TAG, "- onPauase");
    // Stop location updates to save battery, but don't disconnect the GoogleApiClient object.
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        stopLocationUpdates();
        Log.i(TAG,"on pause");
    }
}

@Override
public void onHostDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "- onDestroy");
}
```

1. Import LifecycleEventListener interface

   **import com.facebook.react.bridge.LifecycleEventListener;**
2. register listener in your java class constructor

   **getReactApplicationContext().addLifecycleEventListener(this);**
3. Override necessary methods like above